# How to change the clock in the date component devextreme?

Tags: javascript, devextreme

I have a generic date component from devextreme.

```
  <DxDateBox
    type="datetime"
  />
```

He looks like this

[image]

Instead of a clock, I need to make a linear list of hours and minutes, as it looks like in a standard html component with type datetime-local

[image]

I hid the clock itself by setting the opacity to 0, but I need to put new blocks in their place, but how to do this?
I can’t paste template into the drop-down window.
Make a block and substitute it when opening?